# How to display System.out.print from a function to JOptionPane.showMessageDialog?

Tags: java, swing

How can I display the something like following using JOptionPane.showMessageDialog? I've tried using with String.format but that doesn't appear to work or I'm either doing it incorrectly.

```
public void Display ()
{
    int size_ = rows_ * columns_;
    for (int i = 1; i <= size_; ++i)
    {
        System.out.print( "* ");
        if (i % columns_ == 0)
        {
            System.out.print( "\n ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This question seems a bit confusing to me. Are you trying to get the actual CODE to show in the JOptionPane? Or are you wanting to get the * characters and new lines?

Comment: Format the output in a StringBuilder first then display it in a message dialog.

Comment: @NutterzUK the * characters and new lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to build the desired String(using `append()`). The you can simply call `toString()` on the StringBuilder instance to get the String and use it in your `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog()` method.

Comment: Unfortunately, we're restricted to optionally creating something like this based only on what we've learned thus far. This may be impossible using basic knowledge of classes and control statements. Do you know if it is possible using the most basic knowledge of Java? I realize this is a bit ambiguous, but essentially we're working with scanners, classes, and controls statements here. Arrays and beyond are not allowed. Hope this makes sense.